# Vectorized lookup on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, lookup

I have two DataFrames . . .

`df1` is a table I need to pull values from using index, column pairs retrieved from multiple columns in df2.

I see there is a function `get_value` which works perfectly when given an index and column value, but when trying to vectorize this function to create a new column I am failing...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5)))

df1.columns = list('abcde')

df1.index = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird']

        a   b   c   d   e
cat     0   1   2   3   4
dog     5   6   7   8   9
fish    10  11  12  13  14
bird    15  16  17  18  19

df1.get_value('bird, 'c')

17
```

Now what I need to do is to create an entire new column on `df2` -- when indexing `df1` based on index, column pairs from the `animal`, `letter` columns specified in `df2` effectively vectorizing the `pd.get_value` function above.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5)))

df2['animal'] = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird']

df2['letter'] = list('abcd')

    0   1   2   3   4   animal  letter
0   0   1   2   3   4   cat     a
1   5   6   7   8   9   dog     b
2   10  11  12  13  14  fish    c
3   15  16  17  18  19  bird    d
```

resulting in . . .

```
    0   1   2   3   4   animal  letter   looked_up
0   0   1   2   3   4   cat     a        0
1   5   6   7   8   9   dog     b        6
2   10  11  12  13  14  fish    c        12
3   15  16  17  18  19  bird    d        18
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Deprecation Notice**: `lookup` was [deprecated in v1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#deprecations)

There's a function aptly named `lookup` that does exactly this.

```
df2['looked_up'] = df1.lookup(df2.animal, df2.letter)

df2
 
    0   1   2   3   4 animal letter  looked_up
0   0   1   2   3   4    cat      a          0
1   5   6   7   8   9    dog      b          6
2  10  11  12  13  14   fish      c         12
3  15  16  17  18  19   bird      d         18
```

Comment: Well lockup is the winner here. Can't think of a different approach when there is a built in. And apply kills the performance if tried.

Comment: I tried lookup previously but after your answer found that my issue lied with values which do not look up in the table -- is there a way to handle values which don't look up ?

Comment: @AranFreel I think you could take a look at John Galt's answer.

Answer (score 4):

If looking for a bit faster approach then zip will help in case of small dataframe i.e

```
k = list(zip(df2['animal'].values,df2['letter'].values))
df2['looked_up'] = [df1.get_value(*i) for i in k]
```

Output:

```
   0   1   2   3   4 animal letter  looked_up
0   0   1   2   3   4    cat      a          0
1   5   6   7   8   9    dog      b          6
2  10  11  12  13  14   fish      c         12
3  15  16  17  18  19   bird      d         18
```

As John suggested you can simplify the code which will be much faster.

```
 df2['looked_up'] = [df1.get_value(r, c) for r, c in zip(df2.animal, df2.letter)]
```

In case of missing data use if else i.e

```
df2['looked_up'] = [df1.get_value(r, c) if not pd.isnull(c) | pd.isnull(r) else pd.np.nan for r, c in zip(df2.animal, df2.letter) ]
```

**For small dataframes**

```
%%timeit
df2['looked_up'] = df1.lookup(df2.animal, df2.letter)
1000 loops, best of 3: 801 µs per loop

k = list(zip(df2['animal'].values,df2['letter'].values))
df2['looked_up'] = [df1.get_value(*i) for i in k]
1000 loops, best of 3: 399 µs per loop

[df1.get_value(r, c) for r, c in zip(df2.animal, df2.letter)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.5 µs per loop
```

**For large dataframe**

```
df3 = pd.concat([df2]*10000)

%%timeit
k = list(zip(df3['animal'].values,df3['letter'].values))
df2['looked_up'] = [df1.get_value(*i) for i in k]
1 loop, best of 3: 185 ms per loop


df2['looked_up'] = [df1.get_value(r, c) for r, c in zip(df3.animal, df3.letter)]
1 loop, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

df2['looked_up'] = df1.lookup(df3.animal, df3.letter)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.82 ms per loop
```

Comment: Other way of writing `[df1.get_value(r, c) for r, c in zip(df2.animal, df2.letter)]`?

Comment: What was `df2.shape` here? I expect `lookup` to much faster for larger data.

Comment: Yes indeed. zip method is fast if df is small. Here df2.shape is (4,6). As I said lookup is the winner because builtin.

Answer (score 2):

`lookup` and `get_value` are great answers if your values exist in lookup dataframe.

However, if you've (row, column) pairs not present in the lookup dataframe, and want the lookup value be `NaN` -- `merge` and `stack` is one way to do it

```
In [206]: df2.merge(df1.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'looked_up'}),
                    left_on=['animal', 'letter'], right_on=['level_0', 'level_1'],
                    how='left').drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], 1)
Out[206]:
    0   1   2   3   4 animal letter  looked_up
0   0   1   2   3   4    cat      a          0
1   5   6   7   8   9    dog      b          6
2  10  11  12  13  14   fish      c         12
3  15  16  17  18  19   bird      d         18
```

Test with adding non-existing (animal, letter) pair

```
In [207]: df22
Out[207]:
      0     1     2     3     4 animal letter
0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0    cat      a
1   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0    dog      b
2  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   fish      c
3  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0   bird      d
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  dummy    NaN

In [208]: df22.merge(df1.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'looked_up'}),
                    left_on=['animal', 'letter'], right_on=['level_0', 'level_1'],
                    how='left').drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], 1)
Out[208]:
      0     1     2     3     4 animal letter  looked_up
0   0.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0    cat      a        0.0
1   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0    dog      b        6.0
2  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0   fish      c       12.0
3  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0   bird      d       18.0
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  dummy    NaN        NaN
```

Comment: The approach I used was to find the intersection between the `df1` columns and the `df2` column values... from there I split the `dataframe` into aligned, and unaligned dataframes... used `lookup` on the aligned dataframe -- then concatenated them back together...